# Class HttpDateFormat found but method "getPreferedDateFormat" NOT found

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey-client

While executing POST request using Jersey 2.9 on Eclipse, I can see Class HttpDateFormat but one of it's method "getPreferedDateFormat" is not found ! Any idea ?

I see following error during runtime:

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpDateFormat.getPreferedDateFormat()
```

Answer (score 0):

Old Jersey package had typo in method name : getPreferedDateFormat

With new Jersey package it is: getPreferredDateFormat

I had to upgrade jersey media multipart to version 2.7 and it got correct method name.